# How to use JQuery to preselect radio button on page redirect in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Rails 4.2.6 project where I'm trying to use JQuery to pre-select a radio button on a page redirect.  From the home page -- static_pages/home.html.erb -- a user can choose to click one of three buttons (options):

```
<h2>Select the role that best describes you.</h2> 
<div id="option-1">
  <h2><%= link_to "Option 1", new_user_registration_path, class: "btn-block btn-lg btn-success" %></h2>
</div>
....
<div id="option-2">    
  <h2><%= link_to "Option 2", new_user_registration_path, class: "btn-block btn-lg btn-success" %></h2>
</div> <!-- close workout-occasional -->    
</div>
....
<div id="option-3">
  <h2><%= link_to "Option 3", new_user_registration_path, class: "btn-block btn-lg btn-success", id: "fitness-enthusiast" %></h2>
</div>
```

When a user selects a button, he/she is redirected to the sign-up page, which contains html for radio buttons that identify the type of signup (Option 1, Option 2 or Option 3).  Here's the relevant HTML for the radio buttons generated from users/registrations/new.html.erb:

```
 <div class="form-group radio_buttons required user_signup_as"><label class="radio_buttons required control-label"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Signup as</label>
 <span class="radio"><label for="user_signup_as_option_one"><input class="radio_buttons required" type="radio" value="Option One" name="user[signup_as]" id="user_signup_as_option_one" />Option One</label></span>
 <span class="radio"><label for="user_signup_as_option_two"><input class="radio_buttons required" type="radio" value="Option Two" name="user[signup_as]" id="user_signup_as_option_two" />Option Two</label></span>
 <span class="radio"><label for="user_signup_as_option_three"><input class="radio_buttons required" type="radio" value="Option Three" name="user[signup_as]" id="user_signup_as_option_three" />Option Three</label></span>
</div>
```

My goal is to improve user experience by preselecting the appropriate radio button on the sign-up page based on the button the user clicks on the home page. I tried to accomplish this task by writing the following Jquery / Ajax function and placing it in static_pages.js.erb:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#option-3').click(function(){
console.log("you clicked the Option 3 button");

var value = "Option 3";
console.log(value);

        $.ajax({ 
         type: "Get",
         url: "/users/sign_up",      
            success: function() {           
                $("input[type='radio'][name='user[signup_as]'][value='" + value + "']").prop('checked', true);
                console.log("this is end of the callback function");          
            }
        })
});

});  // end ready
```

I also tried it with the following code in the callback:

```
$('#user_signup_as_option_three').prop("checked", true);
```

The code runs without errors in the console, but no radio buttons are pre-selected.  All console.log messages display okay. I can't figure out why my callback code is not working.  What am I doing wrong & how can I fix it?

***************EDIT*********************

Here's relevant code from my users controller (users_controller.rb):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
load_and_authorize_resource
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

...
# GET /users/new
def new
 @user = User.new  
end

...

private

  def set_user
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

end
```

Here's code for the form which renders the radio buttons (users/registrations/new.html.erb):

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign Up") %>

<h1>Sign Up</h1>

<%= simple_form_for(resource,
   as: resource_name,
   url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs sign-up">
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :signup_as, :collection => [ "Option One", "Option Two", "Option Three"." ], :as => :radio_buttons %>
    <input type="hidden" id="" name='user[signup_as]' value="" />         
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: I guess `$("input[type='radio'][name='user[signup_as]']").length` will be zero while accessing in success function of ajax.. meaning the element is not there in the dom, rather than this approach, try to pass the selected value in data attribute to `users/sign_up`,take it and assign to a input hidden value and then after dom load of page read the hidden value and set the prop checked..

Comment: Regarding the alternative approach ... sounds interesting ... how do I pass the selected value to the signup page, assign it to input hidden value then set the prop? Not clear about how to modify / change the code I have to try this alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can do better way of coding by replacing the id with class and have another attribute with value, lets change the code as below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.option').click(function(){
console.log("you clicked the Option 3 button");

var value = $(this).data("value"); //which gives option1/option2/option3 depends on which div ur clicking
console.log(value);

        $.ajax({ 
         type: "Get",
         url: "/users/sign_up",  
         data : { selectedValue : value}, 
         success: function() {           
                $("input[type='radio'][name='user[signup_as]'][value='" + value + "']").prop('checked', true);
                console.log("this is end of the callback function");          
            }
        })
});

});  // end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Select the role that best describes you.</h2> 
<div class="option" data-value="option1">
  <h2><%= link_to "Option 1", new_user_registration_path, class: "btn-block btn-lg btn-success" %></h2>
</div>
....
<div class="option" data-value="option2">    
  <h2><%= link_to "Option 2", new_user_registration_path, class: "btn-block btn-lg btn-success" %></h2>
</div> <!-- close workout-occasional -->    
</div>
....
<div class="option" data-value="option3">
  <h2><%= link_to "Option 3", new_user_registration_path, class: "btn-block btn-lg btn-success", id: "fitness-enthusiast" %></h2>
</div>
```

So the above code send the `selectedValue:your_selected_value`, you need to parse the `selectedValue` in your ruby controller and assign to a hidden value of the page and try to get the value after page load from hidden value and select the appropriate radio button

Comment: After modifying code, I'm getting "undefined" with  alert($("input[type='radio'][name='user[signup_as]").val()); I'm not sure why that is happening. Also, still trying to figure out how to "parse the selectedValue" & assign it.  I added this field to my signup page:    <input type="hidden" id="signup_option_three" name='user[signup_as]' value=Option Three" />  Is this where I can assign the hidden value?  My apologies, I'm still figuring out how incorporate JavaScript/Jquery into my Rails project.

Comment: can you add your `/users/sign_up` controller and page which renders radio buttons

Comment: check `params[:selectedValue]`, you will get the value of the option you selected and populate that into hidden value using ruby script and use jquery in you html page use document ready and check for your radio button option, you will get it

Comment: I'll need to do more work / research to try to implement this solution.  Still struggling to figure out how to parse the 'selectedValue' & use it to set the radio button.  Unclear on how to do it.