# How do I select a radio button via a link in Rails 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, ruby-on-rails

Maybe this isn't even possible or I'm overthinking the issue. I have tried searching StackOverflow for this specific thing, I've asked for help in my RubyDevelopers slack group and I've paid for help on Codementor.io and still I'm unable to get this working.

This looks close but there was no solution: [How to use JQuery to preselect radio button on page redirect in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835515/how-to-use-jquery-to-preselect-radio-button-on-page-redirect-in-rails)

I'm building a SaaS website in Rails 5 and on the home page(home controller) I have your standard pricing plans listed. To each "Join Now" button, I've linked to the signup page and included the plan id in the url like so: /join-the-club?plan_id=9  for example. I even tried putting /join-the-club?plan_id=9,checked=true, /join-the-club?plan_id.to_s=9 (someone's suggestion on slack).

On the signup page (users controller) there is also the same list of pricing plans as radio buttons. The reason for this is because there is more than one way of getting to this page. There is also a link in the menu that says "Join The Club" that takes them to the same page. Anyway, I would like for the correct radio button to be automatically selected if someone clicks on one of the "Join Now" buttons from the home page pricing table.

OK, now for the code. Here is the link I have on my home page view:

```
<div class="table-body">
  <a href="/join-the-club?plan_id=9"><button class="s1-button">JOIN NOW</button></a>
</div>
```

Then there is the code for the plans on the signup page:

```
<% @plans.each do |plan| %>
  <tr>
    <td class="product-in-table">
     <%= s.label :plan_id, plan.name, :value => plan.id do %>
     <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/qva/cube.jpg" alt="">
     <div class="product-it-in">
      <h3><%= plan.name%></h3>
      <span><%= plan.size %></span>
     </div>
     <% end %>
    </td>
    <td>$ <%= plan.price / 100 %></td>
     <td class="shop-red">Monthly</td>
      <td>
       <%= s.radio_button :plan_id, plan.id,:checked => (plan == @plans.first) %>
      </td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
```

Here is the html for the radio button when I inspect it:

```
<input type="radio" value="9" checked="checked" name="user[subscriptions][plan_id]" id="user_subscriptions_plan_id_9">
```

If you are wondering what "s" is, it's this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :subscriptions do |s| %>
```

So if someone comes to the signup page through the top menu link, /join-the-club then the first plan option is already selected. They just have to leave it or pick another plan. But if they come in through the pricing table, I need the right plan selected. :)

From my understanding, passing the parameter in the URL is just making it ready to save for that db column.

Comment: wow, that's one long question. U sure u can't make it shorter? People are lazy, they don't want to read 5 sheets of paper.

Comment: with this `<%= s.radio_button :plan_id, plan.id,:checked => (plan == @plans.first) %>` you're always selecting the first plan. Try setting a variable like `@selected_plan_id = params[:plan_id]` in your controller, and then, change your line to `<%= s.radio_button :plan_id, plan.id,:checked => (plan.id == @selected_plan_id || ( !@selected_plan_id && plan == @plans.first)) %>`.

Comment: Thanks @fanta . It appears to work great when going through the /join-the-club link from the menu, the first plan is still selected. When picking a plan from the pricing plans on the front page none of the radio buttons are selected. I feel like I'm close ... maybe I put the variable in the wrong place. I put it in the "def new" section of the controller.

Comment: what's the action being executed ?, put the variable in that action. Is there a redirect happening somewhere ?.

Comment: The reason @fanta's solution doesn't quite work may be that `@selected_plan_id` is a string and `plan.id` is an integer. Try `@selected_plan_id.to_i`.

Comment: You're right @Brad It works now!!! :D I'm so glad no javascript was needed and now I can do this for future websites. fanta, it appears I had it in the right place. It should be under "def new". Thank you both so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @fanta and @Brad This is the answer:

Since I need this to happen when creating a new user, I added the variable under "def new" in the users controller:

```
@selected_plan_id = params[:plan_id]
```

Then in the view, I changed my radio button code to look like so:

```
<%= s.radio_button :plan_id, plan.id, :checked => (plan.id == @selected_plan_id.to_i || ( !@selected_plan_id && plan == @plans.first)) %>
```

So if someone uses just the "/join-the-club" link, the first plan will be chosen but if they use one of the links like "/join-the-club?plan_id=x" from the pricing table with the parameter added to the link then the correct radio button for the plan will be selected on the signup page.